# How to connect Epson L355 printer to Wi-Fi network without WPS?

Tags: printer, network-printer, wifi-configuration

We have Epson L355 printer and our router has disabled WPS. We checked all manuals, youtube videos etc. Everything is about connecting with WPS.

How do we connect this printer to our Wi-Fi network using SSID and password?

Comment: You can't. Enable WPS.

Comment: Turns out I can. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used [Epson Product Setup](https://www.epson-middleeast.com/products/printers/inkjet-printers/for-home/epson-l355#drivers).

Really weird, because there's no such tool on other Epson sites.

Comment: It seems to also be at [Epson UK](https://www.epson.co.uk/products/printers/inkjet-printers/for-home/ecotank-l355#drivers) if their Middle East website is unavailable.

Comment: I found what appears to be the Epson Product Setup software [here](https://www.alledruckertreiber.de/2022/07/epson-l355-ecotank-treiber-download.html?m=1).

Answer (score 5):

I have already done this on my new Epson L3150 using my laptop.

How to connect your printer to your router without WPS?

1. Turn on your printer
2. Press and hold together the WiFi+Info buttons to enable "Wi-Fi Direct" mode (Simple AccessPoint), or see in your manual how to enable Direct mode (printer as AP) and do it
   Hold Info button for about 7 seconds to print informatin/status page.
3. Under the  capture find a "Password", it is eight digit code. (NOT wps-pin code, but wifi direct password! they differ)
4. Connect to your printer's WiFi with your PC/notebook or smart phone using the printed password (8 digit code)
5. Go to printer's webpage using its IP, (in my case it was 192.168.223.1), you can find it on the printed information page or in the properties of your wireless connection (gateway = printer's IP).
6. I.e. open your favourite web-browser and type http://192.168..etc (IP address of your printer)
7. Select "Advanced settings" in the combobox on the top of the webpage
8. Go to "Network Settings" > "Wi-Fi", use "Network" tab, scrool to the bottom and press "Setup" button
   Choose your SSID using radio button
9. Write a password of the WiFi of your router, hit "Next", wait
   And you are all done!

Answer (score 0):

Both 1-8, 1-9 steps above do not work.  Commenting here because the above gave me hope.  Once you've connected the trash WIFI setup using WPS, yes, then the advanced network setup steps work.  Rather Google Epson Product Setup and take your chances from there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

1. Your router without WPS.
   1.1. TURN IT OFF.
2. Take a second router with WPS and with wifi settings(password, name, channel, mac isn't necessary) as on your router.
3. Connect your printer to the router with WPS, wait a few minutes (5 will be enough) while printer applies settings.
4. Turn Off your printer correctly (via button).
5. Turn off the second router.
6. Turn On YOUR router(without WPS).
7. Turn On your printer.
8. ....profit!!!!